# Export Problem fbx (Binary Mode not Ascii) in unity

Tags: animation, export, unity

Maybe someone could help me with my problem. I have exported a model from Blender to Unity (fbx Format). Everything looks nice except one thing the shoes are deformed. It looks like there where something like a boundingbox that causes that behaviour. I have checkt already everything in the Weight Paint Mode.

Does anyone have ideas what that could be?

Thank you for your help.[image]

Comment: Does this also happen in Autodesk FBX Review?

Comment: there it looks good..... =( http://postimg.org/image/m5kiaa3xp/

Comment: So then it's most possibly an Unity issue.

Comment: Is it more common to make the animations in unity directly. Create only the mesh, armature, and uv mappings in blender?

Comment: I never used Unity, only UE4 and a bunch of other game dev systems. Once I figured it out, I never had a problem importing my characters there. Maybe a more unity-oriented community has more experience with that?

Comment: I solved the problem by importing the blend file directly as Asset into unity. Now the animation looks exactly like I want.